# Objective-C for in loop nested NSDictionaries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, for-loop, nsdictionary, nested

I've got this data I get from an XML feed and parse as NSDictionaries. The data structure is like this:

```
item = {
  address =     {
    text = "1 Union Street";
  };
  data =     {
    text = "Hello.";
  };
  event_date =     {
    text = "2012-02-27";
  };
  event_type =     {
    text = pubQuiz;
  };
  latitude =     {
    text = "57.144994";
  };
  longitude =     {
    text = "-2.10143170000003";
  };
  name =     {
    text = "Mobile Tester";
  };
  picture =     {
    text = "public://pictures/event_default.png";
  };
  time =     {
    text = "23.00";
  };
  vname =     {
    text = Test;
  };
}
//More items
```

Each sub-section, ie, address, data, event_date etc are all NSDictonaries.

I would like to iterate through the whole collection and grab the "text" inside each of the sections to create an array of "items" with these properties. I've tried using the for..in loop structure in Objective-C but haven't had any success so far. Has anyone got a few pointers? I'm happy to read through any good tutorials or examples on how to traverse nested NSDictionaries.

EDIT:

Alright so, after parsing the XML I get that structure up there. What I would like to do is traverse the "item" structure to extract the "text" fields of all the inner dictionaries - something like this:

```
foreach(item in array of dictionaries) {
  myItem.address = item.address.text;
  myItem.data = item.data.text;
  ...
}
```

And so on. I hope this makes it a little clearer.

So, the part where I'm stuck is where I want to set the properties of the item while traversing the NSDictionaries. This is what I have so far:

```
for(NSDictionary *item in self.eventsArray) {
    for (NSDictionary *key in [item allKeys]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", key);
        id value = [item objectForKey:key];
        if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSDictionary* newDict = (NSDictionary*)value;
            for (NSString *subKey in [newDict allKeys]) {
                NSLog(@"%@", [newDict objectForKey:subKey]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

address
1 Union Street
data
Hello.
...

I'm just not sure how to select the proper attribute in the object I'm creating to set the required property, if that makes any sense?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320511/how-to-iterate-nested-dictionaries-in-objective-c-iphone-sdk

Comment: Just curious, are these dictionaries of dictionaries because it is possible for each item to have something other than text?

Comment: Your description of the output you want is pretty ambiguous; you should provide an example of what it would look like.

Comment: Yes, these are dictionaries of dictionaries, so "item" is a dictionary and "address" is a dictionary.

Comment: yugi - I added a further clarification of what I'm trying to do. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Almo - Sorry if this is a duplicate, I honestly tried searching before I posted. I'll have a look at the solutions there meanwhile. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Honestly, one's first reaction to your question is: So go right ahead, traverse the dictionaries. What problem are you having? Objective-C gives you everything you need here; are you just not seeing it? I suggest you use the block-based enumeration API.

Comment: No probelm, KerrM. I don't get mad when I see duplicates. I just mark them. :)

Comment: Hi @matt - Sorry my initial question wasn't complete - I've added a wee snippet of code with what I have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the items I did the following:

```
id eventsArray = [[[[XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:responseData error:&parseError] objectForKey:@"root"] objectForKey:@"events"] objectForKey:@"event"];
if([eventsArray isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) 
{
    //there's only one item in the XML, so there's only an NSDictionary created.
    for(NSString *item in (NSDictionary*)eventsArray) 
    {
        //check what each item is and deal with it accordingly
    }
} 
else 
{
    //There's more than one item in the XML, an array is created
    for(NSDictionary *item in (NSArray*)eventsArray) 
    {
        for (NSString *key in [item allKeys]) 
        {
          //check what value key is and deal with it accordingly
        }
    }
}
```

And that allows me to access all elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new dictionary called items from the original one (called here dictionaries) :

```
NSMutableDictionary *items = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *dict in dictionaries) 
{
    [items setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"text"] forKey:[dict description]];
}
```

It will create the following dictionary:

```
item = {
address = "1 Union Street",
data = "Hello.",
....
}
```