# Is there a way to loop through nsdictionary in objective C where key values are not known and the dictionary is deeply nested

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Is there a way to loop through nsdictionary in objective C where key values are not known and the dictionary is deeply nested. Can anyone please help? i searched a lot couldn't find a definitive solution for this. 
I will get a JSON string which i am moving into a NSDictinary variable, here some values are encrypted some are not. I need to decrypt only certain parts of the json. I know which key value pair i need to decrypt. (which also is a part of the json string, i.e is available in the outer nest). But for each JSON response the string will change so i don't know where the encrypted key value pair will be. I just know the key name. So i need to loop through the entire json and find those key pairs to decrypt. Also the json is deeply nested.

> Hi thanks for responding here is the sample json

This is a sample json (not the exact string)

```
{
  "DTLS": [
    {
      “VALUE1”: “ASsddcFF12223fdvfvfvffrefcdcssss”
    },
    {
      "VALUE2”: “sdsdd2323edffvfvb4ddcdccvvvrfdc”
    },
    {
      "VALUE3”: "sdsdd2323edffvfvb4ddcdccvvvrfdc"
    },
  ],
  "Decryptkeys":"VALUE1|VALUE2|VALUE3"
  "isSuccessful": true,
  "responseTime": 2014,
  "totalTime": 2014,
  "responseCode": "S",
  "statusCode": 200
}
```

The above response may change in the another server call where DTLS could be nested inside another json key like MAINDTLS, so the only key that i can blindly take is Decryptkeys. I know where this will be. But the ones inside Decryptkeys i.e VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3 maybe nested somewhere deep inside the json.

Comment: Your problem is unclear. It would be better, if you post your JSON response here, and what key you want as Example.

Comment: please provide example for the problem of dictionary that you are having. I can't give any comment just by reading your explaination

Comment: Thanks guys for responding. i have modified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer:

> how to iterate nested dictionaries in objective-c iphone sdk

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40942013/2432053

---

EDIT

Here is modified version:

```
- (id)findflat:(NSString *)keyToFind {

    if([self objectForKey:keyToFind]) {
        return self[keyToFind];
    }

    for(id key in self.allKeys) {
        if ([self[key] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            for (id obj in self[key]) {
                if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                    id res = [obj findflat:keyToFind];
                    if (res) {
                        return res;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: If i pass "DTLS" it successfully searches for it, if i pass VALUE1 it returns nil.

Answer (score 0):

First two if conditions check if value is kind of dictionary or array if so it has to be parsed.
Last if condition if ([self respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)])
This is where you get value.

In my case I have a custom NSObject, what I'm doing here is checking if this object respond to particular key then I'm setting the value...

In your case i believe last if condition should check if key is DTLS...then do your stuff

Hope this helps...

```
-(void)parseDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict{
    for (NSString *key in dict) {
        if([[dict valueForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
            [self parseDictionary:[dict valueForKey:key]];
        }else if([[dict valueForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
            for (NSDictionary* object in [dict valueForKey:key]) {
                [self parseDictionary:object];
            }
        }else if ([self respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)]) {
                [self setValue:[dict valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot but the above solution works perfectly. thanks anyways.